# how to write DRY documentation with code examples in python?

Tags: python, documentation, docstring, mkdocs, mkdocs-material

I am writing documentation for a package that I am creating and I need to put code examples within the SDK in many places, what is the best way of doing this so it is DRY, automated, and tested easily?

To write code documentation I am basically grabbing code examples from the tests directory and putting them in the docstrings. However, this is a problem because every time the tests update then the documentation would also need to be updated as well, which could create a lot of work. Is there a better way of doing this?

I am using [material mkdocs](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/)